# Why not use __if_exists with local variables?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7wy9xh3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the Microsoft-specific `__if_exists` statement says the following (emphasis added):

> Apply the __if_exists statement to identifiers both inside or outside a class. **Do not apply the __if_exists statement to local variables**.

Unfortunately there is no explanation for why you should not apply this to local variables. It compiles fine and has the expected effect, so I'm wondering if anyone knows why they say not to do this. Is it a correctness issue, or a maintainability issue, or something else?

I realize that this is a Microsoft-specific feature and not portable, but let's assume for argument's sake that there's a good reason to use it.

**EDIT**: Some folks are curious why I'm doing this, so here's an explanation. *I realize this is a dirty hack, so unless you have a good suggestion for a better way to do it, please don't bother pointing out that it's gross. It's the least-gross alternative we were able to find given the large size of the code base.*

We have a large body of legacy code (millions of lines) that uses the Microsoft-specific `__FUNCTION__` macro as part of an error logging package. A significant fraction of that code is now wrapped inside lambda functions so that we can catch structured exceptions (with `__try`/`__except`) and still use unwindable objects. Inside those lambda functions, `__FUNCTION__` evaluates to something useless like `` `anonymous-namespace'::<lambda23>::operator() ``, which is not useful for anything. Our workaround for this is to define new `__FUNCTION__`-like macro which checks for the existence of an alternate local variable with the enclosing function name, using `__if_exists`. Due to how the macros work, we can easily switch to the new `__FUNCTION__` substitute and easily define the alternate name variable without changing tons of code, so it's a reasonably clean solution given the limitations. That is, of course, assuming that it's valid to use `__if_exists` this way.

As I said above, I know it's a dirty hack, so please don't tell me how ugly it is unless you have good ideas on how to do it better.

Comment: "To achieve the **most reliable results**, use the `__if_exists` statement under the following constraints."

Comment: Right, but the problem is that the docs don't explain how those guidelines affect reliability. Guidelines without rationale are not very helpful, because it's hard to know whether the guideline applies to a particular situation.

Comment: "Guidelines without rationale are not very helpful". I can't help but think of how massively wide-scale this concept has proven true throughout human history.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for sure, but one guess is a local variable might be optimized away by compiler, and maybe not of course, which renders __if_exists test unrelieable.

And I also don't see the reason to do this for a local variable, you are in that specific scope, you know everything, why you want to test if a local variable exist?

Comment: Good thought on the optimizations. I did a brief test and it seems to still work even with optimizations turned on, but it's possible it would not work in some other scenarios. You also have a good point about this normally being unnecessary for variables in local scope, but I have at least one scenario where it would be helpful.

Comment: Would be interesting to know what scenaria?

Comment: I edited the question to describe the scenario - hopefully it wasn't too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

`__if_exists` is a [dirty old hack](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190828-00/?p=102812) inside Visual C++, with severe implementation limitations as it was only intended for ATL.

Local variables are special because you can have two local variables with the same name:

```
void foo()
{ 
  int i = 1;
  {
    int i = 2;
  }
}
```

This means there's a more complicated datastructure inside the compiler to track them. `__if_exists` has to do a name lookup, which may not be correct for some types of nested scopes like this.

Another historical case is that in Visual C++, `for` wasn't correctly scoped:

```
void foo()
{ 
  for (int i = 1; false; ) { }
  __if_exists(i) // What do you expect? VC++ let i escape.
}
```