# How to properly use __if_not_exists and __if_exists

Tags: c++, standards, redefinition

Currently, I am trying to deal with a problem where I want to prevent variable redefinition. I have currently achieved the avoidance of the redefinition by means of a token paste which can "paste" any given thing to your variable name. However, I do not want more than 1 variable in the same scope.

Current solution (these variables are pasted in by a macro, I do not define them myself):

```
{
  mytype mt_2; // 2 is pasted
  mytype mt_3; // 3 is pasted
}
```

I found `__if_not_exists` and I think it can be the solution to my problem, however, the Microsoft docs state

> Apply the __if_not_exists statement to identifiers both inside or outside a class. **Do not** apply the __if_not_exists statement to local variables.

[[__if_not_exists Statement]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/if-not-exists-statement?view=vs-2019)

My question is, why should I **not** do this?
Is there anybody that uses this statement or can tell me a proper use-case of this statement?

The only (partial/speculative) answer I could find was posted [[here on SO]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009869/why-not-use-if-exists-with-local-variables)

**EDIT 1:**
What I really am trying to accomplish:

```
{
 Logmacro(); // Logmacro() indents and logs
 Logmacro(); // Logmacro() should only log
  {
    Logmacro();  // Logmacro() indents and logs
  }

}
```

Comment: You could provide a bit more context for why you are _trying to deal with a problem where I want to prevent variable redefinition._ (Not that this is actually an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) which can be solved in a better way.)

Comment: Even with your edit, you still could provide more context.  Why would you want `Foo()` to behave that way?  My initial impression is that it is a bad idea because it would be very unusual behavior and therefore would be very surprising to anyone reading the code.  Again, there might be better ways to solve your ultimate goal than this design that you seem to have settled on.

Comment: @jamesdlin see edit, it's for a logger.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not trying to use them at all.

See Raymond Chen's post: [The sad history of Visual Studio’s custom __if_exists keyword](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190828-00/?p=102812)

Besides that, trying to violate the documentation requirement is not useful. It may work for some cases, but be fragile.